# 502 Error returned from API after 2 minutes

Tags: c#, timeout, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, http-status-code-502

I am calling a .NET 7 web API POST endpoint from another C# command line application.

The endpoint is returning a 502 error consistently **after 2 minutes** but the endpoint is still continuing processing even though the **502** is returned. This doesn't happen when I call a debug version locally but happens when I call the deployed version, configured via IIS.

I have tried the following things but none seem to resolve the issue:

- Large timeout on the http client in the c# application that is calling the API
- Increasing the Connection timeout limit in IIS
- Setting keep alive timeout during start up of the web API

Comment: Because you mentioned the `2 minutes + 502 bad gateway` error, I come up with an idea that the [default timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element) for IIS ASP.net core module response is 2 minutes, and when we host the app in IIS, it might use the [out-of-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-8.0) mode. That means the asp.net core module is working like a gateway to receive request and pass to the app hosting in IIS

Comment: so that we might first checking in web.config file to see if the `hostingModel` in `<aspNetCore />` attribute is `outofprocess`, and anyway, we could try to increase the timeout `<aspNetCore requestTimeout="5"`, or we can change `hostingModel="inprocess"`

Comment: by the way, if that doesn't help, pls enable failed request tracing in IIS, and look into the traces to see where's the problematic module